# Js Audio Volume Slider

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, volume

I am new to this and I have a question. how can i put a volume slider? Thank you!!
I can't find any code for the moment that works for me, I hope your help

HTML:  `<a id="play-pause-button" class="fa fa-play">`

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var audio = new Audio("http://21273.live.streamtheworld.com/LOS40_DANCE.mp3");
$('#play-pause-button').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-play'))
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
     $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
     autoplay = true;
     audio.play();
     audio.muted = false;
   }
  else
   {
    audio.muted = true;
     $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
     $(this).addClass('fa-play');
   }
});

audio.onended = function() {
     $("#play-pause-button").removeClass('fa-pause');
     $("#play-pause-button").addClass('fa-play');
};

</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tested this and it works.

HTML

```
<input type="range" id="volume-control">
```

JS

```
let audio = new Audio("http://21273.live.streamtheworld.com/LOS40_DANCE.mp3");

let volume = document.querySelector("#volume-control");
volume.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
audio.volume = e.currentTarget.value / 100;
})
```

I hope it helps

Comment: If you use the "input" event instead of the "change" event, the volume adjusts already while sliding and not only on mouseup.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an input range and I think control the volume with js or use the native controls

So why not just use an `<audio>` element on the html? you can give the attribute `controls` and then you won't even need `$("#play-pause-button")`

```html
<audio src="your_src" controls="true">
```

Or is it due to styling? If so then here's an alternative:

```html
<input id="volume-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
```

```js
const audio = new Audio("http://21273.live.streamtheworld.com/LOS40_DANCE.mp3");
const configure = $("#play-pause-button");
const range = $("#volume-control");
configure.on("click", function () {
    const hasPlayClass = configure.hasClass("fa-play");

    //in nativejs its .classList.toggle() idk about jquery but here's my guess
    configure.toggleClass("fa-play");
    configure.toggleClass("fa-pause");

    audio.muted = hasPlayClass;

    if (hasPlayClass) {
        //did you mean audio.autoplay? Used to be autoplay
        audio.autoplay = true;
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});

range.on("change", () => {
  audio.volume = range.value;
});

audio.on("ended", function () {
    configure.removeClass('fa-pause');
    configure.addClass('fa-play');
});
```

Last option: use a library for audio controls.

On a different note this code was very bad and repetitive, would recommend not using jquery any further since it barely shortened the code here

Comment: Hello @Karizma !! I use JS because I have styles in the "play / pause" button, I tried your code but it still hasn't worked for me. In my code I had a mute action when you press "play / plause" so that the audio is muted, but the transmission of the URL continues since it is a Stream URL from radio fm. therefore I think that line would not go `audio.muted = hasPlayClass;`. in my wed appears the "input range" but wanting to increase / decrease the volume does nothing. I wait for your help. Thank you!

Comment: `audio.muted = hasPlayClass` is the exact same code you had before, but shorter, you can see in the `if` else statement. As for it not working, have you checked the console? Can you log a test inside of `range.on("click")` for a test? I have tried to replicate this situation but It has not worked for me since security errors with audio, so if you can tell me how to replicate, I can help your further.

Comment: this time copy your code perfectly and change `range.on (" change ")` to `range.on (" click ")` as you said and it still doesn't work :(, what if the player works is the "play / pause "but the volume has not yet. I pass a photo of the audio player so you can see that it is not very complex [https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5ObrEGDVHw0/XthuWwitUrI/AAAAAAAAB6A/s1VPwWrvE7Mc95ZuD93jGcGAWn5rX9XhACLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/player.png], but the volume is giving me a headache. I await your answer ..

Comment: I did not mean to say change it to `range.on("click")`, I meant add a `console.log("2")` test inside of the `range.on("change")` function and see if it calls, do you have discord? SO isn't meant for long discussion